# What are the downsides of using only few properties of an object?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I apologize if the title is not clear, I couldn't think of anything else.

So I'm using a simple MVC architecture where I have following packages: `controller, bean, dao`

One of my bean class is `UserDetailsBean` which contains getter and setter methods for lets say 20 types of user details like username, password, address, email, gender, dob etc...

When the user logs in I create an object for `UserDetailsBean` and use only two properties `setUsername()` and `setPassword()` and pass this object to my dao class `UserDetailsDAO` for database validation.

My question is that the `UserDetailsBean` has many getter and setter methods but I'm utilizing only 2 of them during login, does this affect my performance? What if I create another bean class say `UserLoginBean` which has getter and setter for only username and password, does this gives me better performance compared to my previous approach?

**PS:** By performance I mean any help I can get for a more effective and fast working application.

Comment: What do you mean by "performance?"  If you are asking whether the login time will be faster if you shed the unused getters and setters, then the answer is probably no.  If you are asking whether your JVM might have more available memory, then the answer might be yes.

Comment: *"does this affect my performance?"* No, I shouldn't think so (to any great extent). *"What if I create another bean class say UserLoginBean which has getter and setter for only username and password, does this gives me better performance"* I wouldn't think so.  BUT, what I might be tempered to do is have both a login and user interface (where user might extend from login to share common properties), there by reducing what is exposed at each level and restricting the available information to only what's really required, but that's more of a design choice ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen by "performance" I mean any help I can get for a more effective and fast working application.

Comment: @MadProgrammer If that's just a design choice rather than any possible gain in performance then I guess I should stick with what I'm already doing.

Comment: @SaumilSoni So long as you're happy with the amount of information your expose, then by all means ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my knowledge and if I am not mistaken in understanding your question,
**using less of getter and setter functions** **do affect your performance** because their less usage will *lead to less of data movement* , so your code's performance will get affected. 

Getter and setter methods are *not even* particularly *object oriented* (OO).
In fact, they **can damage your code's maintainability**.Moreover, the

> presence of numerous getter and setter methods is a
>   red flag that the program isn't necessarily well designed from an OO
>   perspective.

You'll get even a better idea through this relation that 
**maintainability** is *inversely proportionate* to the *amount of data that moves* between objects.

For better understanding that how they'll affect your performance, you can also refer [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html).